# php session and cookie changing value

Tags: session, cookies

So when a user goes to my site, if they have a session then i will use there session, if they have a cookie and not a session, then a session will be set and if they dont have any then ill set a cookie and a session.

All works but the cookie is changing the value when i reload the site. What am i doing wrong

here is the code

```
if(isset($_SESSION['filekey'])){
    $auth = $_SESSION['filekey'];

} else if(isset($_COOKIE['filekey'])){
    $auth = $_COOKIE['filekey'];
    $_SESSION['filekey'] = $auth;
} else {
    $rand = $upload->genfile(20);
    setcookie("filekey", $rand, time()+3600*24*30);
    $_SESSION['filekey'] = $rand;
    $auth = $_SESSION['filekey'];
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `session_start()` at the top?

Comment: Yeah i have that at the top

Comment: Try setting a simple cookie by itself (outside of your conditions) and read it.